# How to assess the bias created by bias sampling in an area?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

I have a data set where soil was sampled in a given area. The area has a pond in the center, and the pond area soil was sampled at a much higher rate than the other soil in the area. Certain constituents are more abundant near the water, so summary statistics tell an inflated story of the soil values in the area. I want to quantify how much higher the mean is in the dataset compared to the true mean.

I only have this one data set, so I was thinking I could take a spatial stratified random sample of the data, and compare the mean to a random sampling of the data using a t test or something, but I think that would violate the independence assumption. How should I try and quantify this bias?

Comment: You could fit a spatial (geostatistical) model (packages with such functionality include `nlme`, `glmmTMB`, `spaMM`, ...)

Comment: There are many, many, many approaches to this, but the most basic concept to bear in mind is that you can stratify the site into near-pond and away-from-pond areas and estimate the mean concentrations within each stratum (and their standard errors) to make this comparison.  How you make the estimate depends on details of the sampling plan, numbers of samples, and techniques you are familiar with.  Popular choices range widely from area-weighted means using Thiessen polygons to simple IDW to various forms of Kriging.